# ReactJS How to handle this that refers to DOM

Tags: reactjs

In vanilla js if we want to add a listener to a dom we can do like this

```
<div onclick="myFunction(this)">...</div>
```

but wen i do it inside react component this is refers to component class itself. how to handle something like this?

Comment: May I ask why you want a `this` that refers to the Dom? Also you should look up what the `ref` prop does on a component, sounds like this may be what you're looking for.

Comment: same action in react https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-varahamihira-cu2xq?fontsize=14   `this == e.target` on dom event fire

Comment: because i dont want to do document.getElementById in my method, so i'd rather pas the dom itself as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `event` in your function, and then you access DOM element with `e.target`.

For example if you want to handle input change, you can do something like this:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
  username: '',
});

const handleChange = event => {
  event.persist();
  setValues(values => ({
      ...values,
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value 
  }));
};
```

`event.target.id` is the id of DOM element and `event.target.value` is the value of the same element, which in this case is `input`.

```
<input
  id="username"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter username"
  onChange={handleChange}
  value={values.username}
  required
></input>
```

Also

> **Note**:
>
> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call event.persist() on the event, which will remove the synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be retained by user code.

Comment: Please add information about `useState` for `setValues` or just change it with `this.setState`. OP can be confused. :)

Answer (score 0):

In react u should use `onClick` (with capital C) and pass the event to your function

```
<div onClick={(e) => {myfunction(e)}}>...</div>
```

Then in your function, use `event.target` to get the clicked tag.

```
const myfunction = (event) => {
   let id = event.target.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your context, `this` refers to the DOM target element, so you'd define your function as:

```
function myFunction(target) { /* Code here */ }
```

But in react, when you define an input:

```
<input onClick={myFunction} />
```

Your function is given an event not a target, so your function is defined as:

```
function myFunction(event) { console.log(event.target) }
```